# multiple persistence unit eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, osgi, eclipselink

I m using an osgi application with postgresql connection and a persistence.xml that containt some properties like

```
<persistence-unit name="postgres-name"
    transaction-type="JTA">


<properties>
<!--            <property name="show_sql" value="true" /> -->
<!--            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" /> -->

     <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
     <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINEST"/>
      ...many other properties...
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And in another bundle i want to initialize a H2database with its own unitname, so i have declared a new persistence.xml with :

```
<persistence-unit name="h2-unitname"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

<properties>
         ...many properties...
        <property name="eclipselink.allow-zero-id" value="true"/>
         ...many other properties...
```

Problem is when i get EntityManager for postgres database, all work fine, next i get h2 EntityManager and work fine, but next time postgres EntityManager is used, i have an error :

```
Detail: key (id)=(0)  already exist
Call: INSERT INTO TABLE(ID, TEST) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [0, null]
```

I think my property eclipselink.allow-zero-id define in h2 unitname ovveride the postgres EntityManager...

In fact if i use always postgres database with 0 id, all wark fine, because sequence is call, but if i use one time the h2 EntityManager, entity with 0 id don't work anymore because of allow-zero-id.

How can i define separate property for each persistent unitname?

Ask me if you want to see more configuration

thanks by advance

Comment: Are you using pure eclipselink or in combination with aries jpa?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider you are right, its with "Aries JPAContainer 1.0.2 "bundle in servicemix.

Comment: Have you tried with the new Aries JPA 2.x too? Maybe this issue is already fixed? Normally I would expect the properties to be per persistence unit.

Comment: If i could, i can test but i m in servicmix container and i can t update as i wish any bundle in it, and i don t want to have arias 1.0.2 and Aries 2.x as bundle. I will try to find another solution if i can...thanks for help